# СлЕпень или слепЕнь?

Tags: орфоэпия

Как правильно поставить ударение в слове **слепень**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

СлепЕнь, слепнЯ - такая норма зафиксирована в словарях.  Спасибо за вопрос. У нас все говорят слЕпень, слЕпни.

Comment: Да, вот я и засомневалась.))) Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Да, действительно, слепЕнь. Так же непривычно, как и фОрзац.

Comment: Некоторые словари дают допустимым ударение на втором слове в слове форзац.

Comment: ну слепЕнь-то мне ухо не режет. 
Вот слЕпень = я не очень понимаю, откуда такое произношение у большинства носителей. Ничем не мотивировано.

Comment: От кого услышали, тому и научились... Не каждый день со слепнями встречаемся, к счастью.